# What hinges should I use for my overlay cabinet doors?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I need help understanding how to choose the right hinges for my cabinet doors. I have new 3/4" thick cabinet doors, fully overlaying/sitting on the face frame of the cabinet box.  I do not want European hinges, and want the doors to open to approximately 180 degrees (open all the way back to the adjacent cabinet door).
What description do I look for in choosing the right hinges for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use european style hinges, you need to use an overlay hinge such as this type

[image: overlay hinge]

These can be found ast sites such as [Rockler](http://www.rockler.com/product.cfm?page=5830&site=ROCKLER), or in many DIY centers.

Comment: Do I need to get one that says 3/4" on the packaging?  I notice many say 3/8", but have not found a 3/4" one.  Thanks.

Comment: On an overlay hinge, the thickness of your door is immaterial. What matters is how much it overhangs the frame opening. 3/8 sound like you are looking at inset hinges which are not correct. Thise are used with doors that are partially recessed into the frame.

Comment: I understand.  I will only look for overlay hinges (without inset).  Thank You for your help.